# Remove the spaces from my output and print results in percent

Tags: python

[My output image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKkJO.jpg) How to I remove the spaces from my output and also want to print my results in percent

```
def check_letter_frequency():
        fhand = open('phil.txt')
        letter_frequency_dict = dict()
        for wordz in fhand:
            wordz = wordz.lower()
            words = wordz.strip()

            for letter in words:
                if letter in letter_frequency_dict:
                    letter_frequency_dict[letter] += 1
                else:
                    letter_frequency_dict[letter] = 1
    sorted_letter_frequency = [(key, letter_frequency_dict[key]) for key in sorted(letter_frequency_dict, key=letter_frequency_dict.get, reverse=True)]
        print("letter frequency of:")
        letters = []
        from string import ascii_lowercase
        for key, value in sorted_letter_frequency[:8]:
            # letters.append(ley)
            print('{} : {}'.format(key, value))

    check_letter_frequency()
```

My output looks like this:

```
letter frequency of: : 182 e : 108 t : 91 o : 77 h : 67 n : 66 i : 64 a : 64
```

Comment: What is the format of your text file?

Comment: Remove spaces from this line `print('{} : {}'.format(key, value))`

Comment: @MadWombat my format is txt.

Comment: @CodeIt thats not what I meant. I have posted a picture of my output. you can see the first line 182. I want to remove that line.

Comment: What do the actual lines in that file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
# get the total number, excluding spaces
total = sum([val for key,val in sorted_letter_frequency[:8] if key != ' '])
for key, value in sorted_letter_frequency[:8]:
    # ignore space again
    if key == ' ': continue
    # print out frequency as percentage of the total
    print('{} : {}%'.format(key, float(value) / total * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count letters, you need to check for that when you are building your dictionary

```
import string
valid = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
for letter in words:
    if letter in valid:
        if letter in letter_frequency_dict:
            letter_frequency_dict[letter] += 1
        else:
            letter_frequency_dict[letter] = 1
```

As for percents, you need to get the total letter count and use that to calculate percentages

```
total = sum(letter_frequency_dict.values())
for key, value in sorted_letter_frequency[:8]:
    print('{} : {}%'.format(key, (float(value) / float(total) * 100.0))
```